# Ordinary and as. factor based Lorenz curve giving contrasting results

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am reposting my question with minimum reproducible data set as required. I am making Lorenz curves for inequality. same data is giving different results for ordinary Lorenz curve and the one based on factor. In understanding both give totally opposite results.
I am not sure if ascending or descending the data is causing the issue! Can someone help to solve the issue. and further I want to add filter for two or more Lorenz curves in one diagram?. as for ticks 1 and 2. Below are the are the codes. Correct graph is supposed to be below the 45 degree line.
Looking for the solution please.

```
library(gglorenz)
library(tidyverse)
ticks <-  c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
consumption <- c(0, 3, 10, 30, 100, 10, 20, 300, 500, 1000 )
df <-  data.frame(ticks, consumption)
#plotting
df$ticks <- as.factor(df$ticks)
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=consumption)) +
  stat_lorenz(desc = TRUE) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_abline(linetype = "dashed") +
  theme_minimal() +
  hrbrthemes::scale_x_percent() +
  hrbrthemes::scale_y_percent() +
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum_rc() +
  labs(x = "Cumulative Percentage of the farmers",
       y = "Cumulative Percentage of Total Profits/acre",
       title = "Inequality Among farmers")
```

[image: Plot]

for ordinary LC

```
ggplot(df, aes(consumption)) + 
  stat_lorenz() + 
  geom_abline(color = "grey")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: isn't the difference caused by `desc=TRUE` in the first example? This doesn't seem to be related to whether ticks is a factor, as that's not used in the plotting code

Comment: oops thanks! you saved me.